# How can I make hourly backups from my Synology NAS to my LaCie NAS?

Tags: networking, backup, nas, rsync

I have a [Synology DiskStation DS215j](https://www.synology.com/en-global/products/DS215j) and a [LaCie Network Space 2](https://www.lacie.com/support/support_manifest.htm?id=10451). The LaCie has firmware >2.2.3, which allows it to function as an rsync server. Of course, normal network shares are also available.

Now, I want to backup the data (hourly) on the Synology NAS to the LaCie NAS. Synology offers two options:

1. Built-in backup to an rsync server. This isn’t a real backup; it's just a mirror. If you accidentally delete a file, it’s also deleted from the ‘backup.’
2. Synology Time Backup. This does support multiple versions. However, you can only use it to backup to another Synology NAS, not to an rsync server.

Using the SSH access on the Synology NAS, I could also install free software tools, such as rsnapshot, BackupPC, rdiff-backup or Bacula. However, all these tools either:

- Cannot backup to a remote system.
- Require a daemon to be running on the remote system.
- Warn against backing up to a network drive mount, due to limitations regarding hardlinks.

My last resort would be to gain root access to the LaCie NAS. That would allow me to install Debian, and therefore any software I want. But I’d prefer not to go that route, as I would no longer be able to easily update the firmware.

Are there any tools that I could use to achieve hourly backups? Or have I reached the wrong conclusion regarding the tools mentioned above?

**EDIT:** I’ve given up. Using root access and configuring rsnapshot was by far the easiest way. I created [a manual on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/frankkusters/5bb28c4d1ce4aadd0ae1).

Comment: Consider mounting one of Lacie's windows shares on Synology using smbclient and then using something like [bup](https://github.com/bup/bup) to do the actual backup onto it?

Comment: Even though `bup` looks really cool, they themselves mention that the project is not quite mature yet. So I'm hesitant to use it for something as important as backups. Also, using a mounted network drive will make most tools go into 'local' mode, thereby eliminating optimizations regarding reading of data. I was really hoping to somehow use the rsync daemon that's running on the LaCie nas.

Answer (score 1):

Since the LaCie Network Space 2 can also be used as a regular USB drive, you can attach it directly to the Synology NAS using the USB port. You can then use Synology Time Backup for hourly backups (after formatting the partition to ext4).

Note that the LaCie firmware limits the USB partition to 500GB.

Comment: Although this works, I'm not marking this answer as accepted. There are two disadvantages: 1) the disk space limitation, obviously and 2) the NAS's have to be physically close to each other.